# Mongo not updating documents that were not in the DB when I launched my server

Tags: java, mongodb, esper

I'm working with Mongo and Esper in Java. Once I launched the esper server, I start adding documents and in one of my listeners I have to update some of those documents (one per time). The problem is that Mongo only updates those documents if they were in the database BEFORE I started the server, but not if I have just inserted them.

I'm running this code:

```
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
searchQuery.append("symbol", newEvents[0].get("symbol"));
searchQuery.append("fecha", newEvents[0].get("fecha"));

BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
newDocument.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("SMA10", ((Double) newEvents[0].get("valor")).toString()));

col.update(searchQuery, newDocument);
```

Does anyone have a clue what can be happening? If there is any other information you need, please just let me know.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In `MongoDB`, **update** method can either replace the existing document or update specific fields in existing document.

If you want to `update` document which is not there in your `DB`, you've to use **save** method. It performs special update, called **upsert** operation which'll insert the document if it is not exist.

check the [MongoDB Manual for Update and Save](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/).

Comment: Hi Arthan, thanks for replying.

I want to update a document that it IS in the DB. In fact, I have already checked that when I call the update, the document is there. I guess that the problema is not in the code I have wrote for the update because it works, but only when the document is in the DB from a previous execution.

So my problem is that I want to update a document I have inserted in the current execution, and that's the moment is not working.